# Find a bunch of randomly sorted images on disk and copy to target dir

Tags: linux, bash, random, copy, find

For testing purposes I need a bunch of random images from disc, copied to a specific directory. So, in pseudo code:

```
find [] -iname "*.jpg"
and then sort -R
and then head -n [number wanted]
and then copy to destination
```

Is it possible to combine above commands in a single bash command? Like eg:

```
for i in `find ./images/ -iname "*.jpg" | sort -R | head -n243`; do cp "$i" ./target/; done;
```

But that doesn't quite work. I feel I'll need an 'xargs' somewhere in there, but I'm afraid I don't understand xargs very well... would I need to pass a 'print0' (or equivalent) to all  seperate commands?

[edit]

I left out the final step: I'd like to copy the images to a certain directory under a new (sequential) name. So the first image becomes 1.jpg, the second 2.jpg etc. For this, the command I posted does not work as intended.

Comment: what seems to be the problem ? I works just fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command that you specified also will work without any issues. It works for me well. Can you point out the exact error you are facing.
Meanwhile,
**This will just do the trick for you:**

`find ./images/ -iname "*.jpg" | sort -R | head -n <no. of files> | xargs -I {} cp {} target/`

Comment: Can you explain what the '-i' parameter of xargs does, exactly? Man page is being unhelpful.

Comment: `-I` replaces the brackets '{}' with the input from find, sort and head (or the initial-arguments with names read from standard input) and it's separator is the new line character.
So it basically aligns the output of the previous commands and executes the `cp` command on it.

Comment: Ah, so basically it puts a newline after each found item?

Comment: No it rather removes the newline character from the output of the find, sort and head command. You may try getting the output of the command above without using `xargs` to see for yourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `shuf -n`.

Example:

```
find ./images/ -iname "*.jpg" | shuf -n 10 | xargs cp -t ./target/
```

It would copy 10 random images to `./target/`. If you need 243 just use `shuf -n 243`.

Answer (score 2):

According to your edit, this should do :

```
for i in `find ./images/ -iname "*.jpg" | sort -R | head -n2`; do cp $i ./target/$((1 + compt++)).jpg; done;`
```

Here, you add a counter to keep track of the number of files you already copied.

Comment: The problem of using the find command like this, is that it will break when the filenames have whitespace in them.

Comment: @user000001 good point. setting `IFS=$'\n'` right before the for loop should correct this issue